# Exception of retrieving the COM class factory for component

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, interop

I have a SSIS package which is used to exported SQL Server data to an Excel file through Interop.

When I executed the package from stored procedure, the execution failed and showed following error.

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

And here is my stored procedure cmd.

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test_SSIS]
AS
begin
DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000)
set @cmd= 'dtexec /f "D:\project\toExcel.dtsx"'
exec xp_cmdshell @cmd
end
```

I've search a lot to see others fixes but most of them are related to IIS settings. Those are not the answer I want because I do not use web service. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you have read and write permissions for destination folder?

Comment: Can you post the definition of your Stored Procedure call?

Comment: Have you checked which Windows account the SSIS package is getting executed under? You may need to give that account Launch and Activation Permissions on the {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} class ID (Microsoft Excel Application) in Component Services's DCOM Config.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes I give my computer windows acoount Launch and Activation Permissions in DCOM Config. But it did not work.